# 2008 Hyundai Accent: DIY Ignition Lock Cylinder Replacement without key programming?

Tags: hyundai, ignition, key, ignition-key, accent

**Background:** neither key would turn in the ignition after an hour of trying various things. Same/similar issue as in this thread, I think: https://www.reddit.com/r/Cartalk/comments/2pwlul/key_wont_turn_in_ignition_on_2008_hyundai_accent/ Roadside assistance got it to turn by spraying WD40 and hammering on the end of the key while turning it with pliers. Additionally, we had the same problem in 2014. The dealership replaced the cylinder and had it "coded" (i.e. mechanically matched) to our existing keys. So our doors locks still match the ignition keys right now. The ignition turns fine for the moment, but I imagine this problem will reoccur. Our keys are somewhat worn, so I think using a new cylinder with new matching keys would be best.

**Full car info:** 2008 Hyundai Accent, GLS 4-Door, SEDAN 4-DR, 1.6L L4 DOHC 16V (purchased in Ontario, Canada)

**I want to do this myself, but I can't determine whether I need a dealership to do some sort of programming.**

## Part I would like to buy:

https://www.thewrenchmonkey.ca/products/auto-parts/bwd/CS1090L/

## Question: if I buy the part online and do this myself, do I need to have the dealer (or someone) do programming anyway?

The part's description says both

> This part is also a safety attribute since it does not accept any key which is not loaded with transponder code.

**and**

> Key Programmable: No

I'm confused about how this works. If you can't program the keys, then how can they be made to match my car's transponder? (Where it says "Coding: Coded," I think that just means that the keys have been physically cut to match the tumblers inside the cylinder.) Or do I need someone to reprogram the transponder to match the keys...? I would love to be able to just replace the ignition lock cylinder and use the new keys that come with it. (Then I would just have different keys for the doors, and I could always have a locksmith match the doors to the new keys later on, or try that myself.)

Comment: Those parts wont work. The knock off usa or asian knock offs, dont have immobilizer wiring and wont work in canadian ca

Comment: sorry comment got cut. Wont work need 370 buck hyundia part with immobilizer wiring not knock off parts.

Comment: @MarkWolovetz thanks, though I ended up just having a locksmith clean out the cylinder and replace the pins back in September. No problems since!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record I am an automotive locksmith of over 20 years so I hope that I will be able to answer your question and any additional you may have.

The cylinder is pretty straight forward to replace. The one you have listed will work fine tho the keys do not look to have the chips in them, so you would need a chipped version duplicated to match them for programming. You are correct the "coded" part means the keys are already cut for the cylinder they come with.

To remove your old ignition you will need to remove the dash panel around it, remove the transponder key amplifier from around the ignition housing, then turn the key to the ACC (some are to the ON position). Look for a small hole in the lock housing (about 1-2 inches back) and use a small pick to press in the retainer pin. The cylinder will slide out. On your new cylinder, turn your key to acc or on position and then just insert it in to the housing. All done.

As for the programming, this can only be done with certain tools diagnostically or by direct eeprom writing. I recommend you just call a local locksmith to do it but there is another way I will go over if you want to try. (Do not just tape the old key to the transponder antenna and leave it under the dash)

Buy a HY6/HY022 KEY SHELL. Take this to a hardware store and have them duplicate the new key that came with your replacement ignition. Verify it works your ignition. Have them make a metal key copy of your original OLD key (for the door). Now, you need to remove the chip from your old key. I usually use a wire brush on a grinder to remove the rubber off the head of the key slowly. The transponder will be located in the lower left or lower right. Its small black wedge shaped device. Place this chip inside of your duplicated key shell and the job is done.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful! A few questions if you don't mind: 1. What do you make of the part description, where it says "it does not accept any key which is not loaded with transponder code"? If they have no chips, I don't understand what that sentence means. 2. I think I understand the removal/install except I'm not sure where the transponder key amplifier is (doesn't appear in Haynes manual)--not sure what that looks like exactly. Any ideas there?

Comment: The description is just some gibberish where they are trying to make it sound fancy by saying the lock is a safety feature. Its meaningless. They probably sell locks that come with transponder keys and probably use this statement in all the descriptions. The manuals may be based on the US models which do not have transponders. Where you insert your key, the key antenna is basically right around this behind the dash trim. You will see a clear plastic ring for lighting. Its built in with this..

Comment: Okay thanks, that clears it up nicely! It looks like some vendors won't sell to non-locksmiths. Any recommendations? I'm also wondering if I could 3d-print something in a pinch.

Comment: Looks like this one would sell to me. Do you think this looks like the right part? https://www.lockpicks.com/hy022pt-chipless.html

Comment: Also, I'm thinking about getting the key code from the dealer, and making the new cylinder match the old keys (but still use new wafers & keys with shells). That way I don't have to carry 2 sets of keys, etc. Are you at all able to tell me which wafer type/number I need? I want to avoid buying a giant kit: https://www.clksupplies.com/collections/automotive-pinning-kits/products/hyundai-kia-high-security-regular-pinning-kit-a-36-102 
I also found this, but I'm not sure if it's the right wafer set (but it does have "HY22" in the description): https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32858882730.html

Comment: Yes the key shell looks fine if they will sell to you if not you can just find it easy enough on ebay or amazon. The locksmith suppliers generally only sell to locksmiths. I would strongly advise against using your old key. Its likely very worn and your main problem. In fact if you chose to not go with a new coded cylinder then I recommend that you just call a local reputable locksmith to rebuild your original cylinder (replace wafers/springs) and cut you a new key to code (no duplication). If you choose to rebuild your cylinder yourself then still get a code cut key made.

Comment: Thanks again. New problem when trying to change the cylinder out. The new one has a metal collar where the amplifier ring needs to go. Can I just pull it apart? I tried but don't want to force it if it's just the wrong part. Photos here: https://imgur.com/a/lAPOpmv

Comment: Nah, do not try to force it. Those antenna's break easy. The collar probably comes off and then you can put the antenna on and use your original collar. If it does not come off you may want to consider returning it and trying an oem one out of Korea like this. https://tinyurl.com/yxlrorjf

Comment: Okay sounds good. I've had a couple locksmiths look at the keys, and they both say the keys are fine--esp since I've never had a problem opening any of the other locks in the car. I'm thinking maybe I can get away with just having a locksmith clean out my ignition lock and replace the wafers & springs to the same code. If that doesn't help, then I'll have to go the more aggressive route you've recommended. Either way I've avoided a $550+ expense, which is helpful as my wife and I are both students. Thanks for all your help!